# Not able to solve the version conflict

Tags: android

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
}
```

Error:(30, 0) Version: 6.1.71 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'? Can you try this out as the error is saying.

Comment: Its not working its giving this error
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> just bump the version of play services to 10.0.1
> ```

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'<---- change
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Its not working its giving this error
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'